# jar file not taking images if i change the locatioon of jar file

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource, imageicon

I have created a jar file with some Images, but if I change the location of the jar viz., c to D directory, images are not showing. The jar file is showing Images if I keep Images where jar file exist but if I change the location of the jar file other than location of the Images, jar file not showing the Images.  Please help me.

For loading images the code does this:

```
Icon ic=new ImageIcon("Label.jpg"); 
I have created a jar file with some Images, but if I change the location of the jar viz., c to D directory, images are not showing. The jar file is showing Images if I keep Images where jar file exist but if I change the location of the jar file other than location of the Images, jar file not showing the Images.  Please help me.
```

For loading images the code does this:

```
Icon ic=new ImageIcon("Label.jpg");
```

The codes are :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class sk extends JFrame
{
BufferedImage img;
JFrame f;
JPanel p,p1;
JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6;
File fl;
    JLabel l=new JLabel("Process Status:");
JButton b=new JButton("Browse");
JButton b1=new JButton("Submit");

    public sk()
    {
    BufferedImage img;
    f=new JFrame("Akritiv.1.0");
    Container fc=f.getContentPane();

   BufferedImage img= null;
   try {
 Icon ic=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Label.jpg")));   
 Icon ic1=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/fig.jpg"))); 
 Icon ic2=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/na.jpg"))); 
 Icon ic3=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/logo1.jpg")));
 Icon ic4=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/status1.jpg"))); 
 Icon ic5=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/ver.jpg")));  
 }catch (IOException e) {}


//Icon ic=new ImageIcon("Label.jpg");
//Icon ic1=new ImageIcon("fig.jpg");
//Icon ic2=new ImageIcon("na.jpg");
//Icon ic3=new ImageIcon("logo1.jpg");
 //Icon ic4=new ImageIcon("status1.jpg");
 //Icon ic5=new ImageIcon("ver.jpg");


 p=new JPanel();
p1=new JPanel();
l1=new JLabel(ic);
l2=new JLabel(ic1);
l3=new JLabel(ic2);
l4=new JLabel(ic3);
l5=new JLabel(ic4);
l6=new JLabel(ic5);


//l5.setBounds(5,200,30,10);


b.setBounds(50,100,150,100);

p.add(l1);

p1.add(b);
p1.add(b1);

b.addActionListener(new AL());
b1.addActionListener(new BL());

fc.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
l3.setBounds(10,300,200,300);
l4.setBounds(180,250,70,50);
ll.setBounds(250,400,500,150);
fc.add(p);
fc.add(l6);
fc.add(p1);

//fc.add(b1);
 fc.add(l);

fc.add(l2);
fc.add(l3);
fc.add(l4);
fc.add(l5);
fc.add(ll); 
f.pack();
fc.setBackground(Color.blue);
f.setSize(813,455);
f.setVisible(true);
f.setResizable(false);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }

public class AL implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
 JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
 fc.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.PLAIN,9));
  int choice=fc.showOpenDialog(f);
 if(choice==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
 {
  try{
 String filename=fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

 fl=new File(filename);
 }
  catch(Exception e){}
  }
  }
 }

 public class BL implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

if(ae.getSource()==b1)
{
 l.setText("Please wait...");
 try
{
new shyam(fl);
l.setText("completed");
}
catch(Exception e){}
}
}
}

 public static void main(String arg[])
 {
  sk ob=new sk();
 }
 }
```

Comment: What code are you using to load the images?  Are the images actually embedded within the Jar file?

Comment: You need to provide more information about the structure of your Jar, and how you are loading the Images.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes images are embedded in that jar file

Comment: Icon ic=new ImageIcon("Label.jpg");
Icon ic1=new ImageIcon("fig.jpg");
Icon ic2=new ImageIcon("na.jpg");
Icon ic3=new ImageIcon("logo1.jpg");
Icon ic4=new ImageIcon("status1.jpg");
Icon ic5=new ImageIcon("ver.jpg");
p=new JPanel();
p1=new JPanel();
l1=new JLabel(ic);
l2=new JLabel(ic1);
l3=new JLabel(ic2);
l4=new JLabel(ic3);
l5=new JLabel(ic4);

Comment: Code to load the images, please! Are you using any absolute path?

Comment: @VijayKumarSingh Update your question with the code instead. It will be easier to read. Also, describe the structure of your JAR file and where the Images are located.

Comment: The jar file is showing Images if I keep Images where jar file exist but if I change the location of the jar file other than location of the Images, jar file not showing the Images

Comment: If your JAR file does not contain the Images, then it obviously will not be able to load the images unless you also move the Images. It would be better putting the images, unless you also use absolute paths. inside the jar, and load them from there.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with how you are loading the images...

```
Icon ic=new ImageIcon("Label.jpg"); 
Icon ic1=new ImageIcon("fig.jpg"); 
Icon ic2=new ImageIcon("na.jpg"); 
Icon ic3=new ImageIcon("logo1.jpg"); 
Icon ic4=new ImageIcon("status1.jpg"); 
Icon ic5=new ImageIcon("ver.jpg"); 
p=new JPanel(); 
p1=new JPanel(); 
l1=new JLabel(ic); 
l2=new JLabel(ic1); 
l3=new JLabel(ic2); 
l4=new JLabel(ic3); 
l5=new JLabel(ic4);
```

`ImageIcon(String)` assumes that the `String` parameter is a file name.  In you example, it is equivalent as saying `new ImageIcon("./Label.jpg")`, which is, please load the image from my current execution location called `Label.jpg`.

Embedded resources are not files and can't be treated as such.

You should be using

```
Icon ic=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Label.jpg"));
```

In fact, you should avoid `ImageIcon` and go straight to using [`ImageIO` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) instead.

```
Icon ic=new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Label.jpg")));
```

`ImageIO` will at least throw an exception if it can't find/load the named resource.

Comment: +1 for it all but especially the last sentence in regard to exceptions. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson All hail `ImageIO`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am unable to implement your suggestion Please implement if you can.

Comment: What can't you implement?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have posted my whole code and I am unable to sort out exception

Comment: @MadProgrammer Please verify the codes where I am doing wrong and correct the whole if you spent some time. Thanks

Comment: @MadProgrammer I Have succeeded to compile and run the program. But problem is that when I am creating its jar file, it is not executing Why ?

Comment: @VijayKumarSingh In order for a Jar program to be "executable", it requires a entry within a manifest file.  Check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) for more details

Comment: @MadProgrammer : The Jar executing but problem remains as such. When I move the jar file from the image location to other location, images are not visible. Can you review and edit my codes please ?